# How to convert a python string(include '\b') to a raw string?

Tags: python

I use Maya to render my cartoon, and got a problem when I programming with python.
Maya gives me an string variable which is a path, and I want to convert it to a normalized path. However, when it comes to '\b', I totally failed to play with it. Here's the problem:

I want to convert the string in **paths** whose value looks like 'D:\notebook\bot' to 'D/notebook/bot':

```
paths = ['D:\notebook\bot', 'D:\newworld']
for p in paths:
    p = '{0!r}'.format(p).replace('\\', '/').replace(':','')
    print p
```

The output is :

```
D/notebook/x08ot
D/newworld
```

See, the \n is correctly printed out as /n, however, \b is being escaped as /x08.
How can I achieve what I want? Note I can't format the input paths as:

```
paths = [r'D:\notebook\bot', r'D:\newworld']
```

because it's passed from Maya.
Python version is 2.6.

Comment: If they're really being passed from Maya like that then they're broken in the source and there's no reliable way to fix it.

Comment: How exactly do you get the string from Maya?  Declaring the string as you did in your first code example will automatically result in '\b' being converted to '\x08'.

Comment: I assume you meant the \ in paths should be `"D:\\notebook\\bot", "D:\\newworld"` ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer I came up with was to use the re module and make all the strings "raw" strings. For more info about raw strings check out http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html

```
import re

paths = [r'D:\notebook\bot', r'D:\newworld']

for p in paths:
    result = re.sub(r':?\\', "/", p)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your MAYA files are .MA (Maya Ascii) you can open them in a text editor and search and replace the paths manually.

Or, do it programmatically using perl outside of Maya:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\Qold-path\E/\Qnew-path\E/g' Your.MA
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution to convert str to raw string (converts control characters in string to it original escape sequences representation). Works with '\a', \b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v' . List of all escape sequences is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

```
def str_to_raw(s):
    raw_map = {8:r'\b', 7:r'\a', 12:r'\f', 10:r'\n', 13:r'\r', 9:r'\t', 11:r'\v'}
    return r''.join(i if ord(i) > 32 else raw_map.get(ord(i), i) for i in s)
```

Demo:

```
>>> file_path = "C:\Users\b_zz\Desktop\fy_file"
>>> file_path
'C:\\Users\x08_zz\\Desktop\x0cy_file'
>>> str_to_raw(file_path)
'C:\\Users\\b_zz\\Desktop\\fy_file'
```